# Show uploaded images with collectionfs using filesystem

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to show my uploaded images to the people who visit the app.

I still haven't removed the packages `insecured` or `autopublish` from my project.

I have a function like this one:

```
$scope.upload = (event) => {
  var file = event; //assuming 1 file only
  console.log(file);
  if (!file) return;
  Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success', fileObj);
    }
  });
}
```

which stores the image in my local machine

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "/home/user/uploadedimages"})]
});
```

in my `meteor mongo` console, when I do `show.collections` I get `cfs.images.filerecord` which has the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "yqEzEH2us7SZveDm2",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "Screenshot from 2016-05-11 14:38:59.png",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-11T18:38:59.636Z"),
        "size" : 607292,
        "type" : "image/png"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-15T03:04:40.447Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "images" : {
            "name" : "Screenshot from 2016-05-11 14:38:59.png",
            "type" : "image/png",
            "size" : 607292,
            "key" : "images-yqEzEH2us7SZveDm2-Screenshot from 2016-05-11 14:38:59.png",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-15T03:04:40Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-15T03:04:40Z")
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**

How do I display the uploaded images to the client.

I've read that you do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
  <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" width="400px" alt="">
</div>
```

But this doesn't render the image or shows anything at all. I know I can see the array without subscribing cause I still haven't removed the `autopublish` package from meteor.

Comment: i'm not familiar with angular. but wouldn't there be any braces or something to make `image in images` a variable loop? I'm Blaze & React guy. pardon me if it sounds noob.

Comment: the angular part is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: the question is where do you upload? Meteor will serve public content in the public folder, so if you upload the pic in that folder, and you reference the proper URL in the img tag, it will show the image when the url is updated. Now, you'll probably encoutner another typical problem, in dev mode, which is that the hot code reload in Meteor triggers when something changes in the public folder, so likely your app will reload when the image is uploaded.
The trick I had to use is upload to another folder, and write a route to server files from that folder.

Comment: Hi @MrE I wouldn't like to have the images store in the same app folder since I do manual deployments I would have to copy and paste the folder with uploaded images in the new build. I would like to have a different folder in the server outside the app folder for the uploaded images. Could you show me an example of what you did?

Answer (score 2):

You can use var fileObj.url(); to get the url of the uploaded image in your success callback. For instance:

```
var url = fileObj.url({brokenIsFine: true});
console.log(url);
```

Comment: your solution works. I've tested it locally and it's working, but I ask, would doing this in production, since I'm deploying manually I have to rebuild the app over and over, would building the app again means losing all the files uploaded before? I can't seem to find the folder it's being uploaded to `url /cfs/files/images/...`

I've also done another solution via nginx to upload to a folder outside the app and just serve it via nginx reverse proxy which works as well and I have the folder outside the app but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.